# Count and Sort with Pandas

Tags: python, sorting, pandas, count, group-by

I have a dataframe for values form a file by which I have grouped by two columns, which return a count of the aggregation. Now I want to sort by the max count value, however I get the following error:

> KeyError: 'count'

Looks the group by agg count column is some sort of index so not sure how to do this, I'm a beginner to Python and Panda.
Here's the actual code, please let me know if you need more detail:

```
def answer_five():
    df = census_df#.set_index(['STNAME'])
    df = df[df['SUMLEV'] == 50]
    df = df[['STNAME','CTYNAME']].groupby(['STNAME']).agg(['count']).sort(['count'])
    #df.set_index(['count'])
    print(df.index)
    # get sorted count max item
    return df.head(5)
```

Answer (score 101, accepted):

I think you need add `reset_index`, then parameter `ascending=False` to [`sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) because `sort` return:

> FutureWarning: sort(columns=....) is deprecated, use sort_values(by=.....)
>     .sort_values(['count'], ascending=False)

```
df = df[['STNAME','CTYNAME']].groupby(['STNAME'])['CTYNAME'] \
                             .count() \
                             .reset_index(name='count') \
                             .sort_values(['count'], ascending=False) \
                             .head(5)
```

Sample:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'STNAME':list('abscscbcdbcsscae'),
                   'CTYNAME':[4,5,6,5,6,2,3,4,5,6,4,5,4,3,6,5]})

print (df)
    CTYNAME STNAME
0         4      a
1         5      b
2         6      s
3         5      c
4         6      s
5         2      c
6         3      b
7         4      c
8         5      d
9         6      b
10        4      c
11        5      s
12        4      s
13        3      c
14        6      a
15        5      e

df = df[['STNAME','CTYNAME']].groupby(['STNAME'])['CTYNAME'] \
                             .count() \
                             .reset_index(name='count') \
                             .sort_values(['count'], ascending=False) \
                             .head(5)

print (df)
  STNAME  count
2      c      5
5      s      4
1      b      3
0      a      2
3      d      1
```

---

But it seems you need [`Series.nlargest`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.nlargest.html):

```
df = df[['STNAME','CTYNAME']].groupby(['STNAME'])['CTYNAME'].count().nlargest(5)
```

or:

```
df = df[['STNAME','CTYNAME']].groupby(['STNAME'])['CTYNAME'].size().nlargest(5)
```

> The difference between `size` and `count` is:
>
> [`size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html#pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size) counts `NaN` values, [`count`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.count.html#pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.count) does not.

Sample:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'STNAME':list('abscscbcdbcsscae'),
                   'CTYNAME':[4,5,6,5,6,2,3,4,5,6,4,5,4,3,6,5]})

print (df)
    CTYNAME STNAME
0         4      a
1         5      b
2         6      s
3         5      c
4         6      s
5         2      c
6         3      b
7         4      c
8         5      d
9         6      b
10        4      c
11        5      s
12        4      s
13        3      c
14        6      a
15        5      e

df = df[['STNAME','CTYNAME']].groupby(['STNAME'])['CTYNAME']
                             .size()
                             .nlargest(5)
                             .reset_index(name='top5')
print (df)
  STNAME  top5
0      c     5
1      s     4
2      b     3
3      a     2
4      d     1
```

Comment: @jul - Be free omit it, because in your data working with Series, not DataFrame

Comment: I am trying that with Series and get `TypeError: set_index() got an unexpected keyword argument 'name'`

Comment: @jul - so `print (type(df[['STNAME','CTYNAME']].groupby(['STNAME'])['CTYNAME'].size() .nlargest(5)))` return `Series` ?

Comment: I have my own DataFrame. `df.groupby('track_id').count().reset_index(name='count')` returns the `TypeError: set_index() got an unexpected keyword argument 'name'`, and `df.groupby('track_id').count()` is a `DataFrame`.

Comment: @jul - I think need `df.groupby('track_id').size().reset_index(name='count')`

Comment: Indeed. `df.groupby('track_id').size().reset_index(name='count').sort_values('count', ascending=False)` works.

Comment: I got error: `TypeError: set_index() got an unexpected keyword argument 'name'`. Following worked for me (diff data and prob through):
`df[[col1, col2]].groupby(col1).count().sort_values(col2, ascending=False)`

Comment: @ak2205 - it means it is not `Series`, use `.reset_index()` and then if necesary `rename(columns={'index':'col'})`

Answer (score 21):

I don't know exactly how your df looks like. But if you have to sort the frequency of several categories by its count, it is easier to slice a Series from the df and sort the series:

```
series = df.count().sort_values(ascending=False)
series.head()
```

Note that this series will use the name of the category as index!

Answer (score 6):

Some of the existing answers are outdated. The following solution works for listing a column and the frequency of its distinct values:

```
df = df[col].value_counts(ascending=False).reset_index()
```

Answer (score 2):

I agree with @Christoph Schranz to take slice a series from dataframe

```
df[['STNAME','CTYNAME']].groupby('STNAME')['CTYNAME'].count().nlargest(3)
```

Answer (score 0):

For sort the rows by count of a colum, you can do this:

```py
sorted_index = df['col'].value_counts().index
df.set_index('col').loc[sorted_index].reset_index()
```

If you want to keep the old index, do this:

```py
sorted_index = df['col'].value_counts().index
df['index'] = df.index
df.set_index('col', drop=True).loc[sorted_index].reset_index().set_index('index', drop=True)
```