# Count and sort based on count (TypeError: set_index() got an unexpected keyword argument 'name' )

Tags: python, dataframe

my question is similar to this:

[Count and Sort with Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40454030/count-and-sort-with-pandas)

However, the answer seems outdated

```
df = df[['STNAME','CTYNAME']].groupby(['STNAME'])['CTYNAME'] \
                             .count() \
                             .reset_index(name='count') \
                             .sort_values(['count'], ascending=False) \
                             .head(5)
```

It throws:

```
TypeError: set_index() got an unexpected keyword argument 'name'
```

Simply I want to count distinct values of a column and show them sorted by their frequencies.

Answer (score 0):

The following solution works:

```
df = df[col].value_counts(ascending=False).reset_index()
```